# Can anybody recognize this sound effect?

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, sound, sound-effects-recording

Im trying to find out what kind of soundeffect this is?
Does anybody recognizes it?

Comment: The 'zip' noise just before the second clunk sounds like a motor or an actuator of some sort - could be lots of things. It sounds as though it could be picking something up, moving, and then dropping the item again (or dropping one, moving, and then picking up another) - Changing tools/heads maybe? But I can't be sure

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about locating or naming a particular resource, sound, composition or instrument are often relevant only to the original asker, don't add any value to the stack exchange network & are rarely useful to future readers.

Comment: Sounds very special. Unless you create this noise yourself it will be hard to have to right association. Guessing the wind is part of the recording, so it seems to be outsides, like the picture is suggesting, too. The (last) "knock" sound seems to come from something wooden, or boxy, or both. The "zip" sound reminds me of a tensed string. Someone might be constructing something or maybe there is some action with a bow. Just guessing.

Comment: That‘s how tape recorders used to sound, sometimes …